# Linux fails to set the correct resolution for my monitor which causing a black screen saying "Out of range"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, display, vga

In my monitor it says "Out of Range" black screen. Where i need to set the VGA output resolution to 1024x768 having 60hz or 70hz.

Here is the following lines i have tried but it fails.

```
    $ cvt 1024 768
    $ xrandr --newmode shvga 74.50 1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798
    $ xrandr --addmode VGA-1 shvga
    $ xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode shvga
```

**Follow up:** [SOLVED](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222119/ubuntu-12-10-how-to-set-the-resolution-to-1024x768-and-correct-rate-using-com)

```
1) how do to i tell penguin, please set my refresh rate to 60 or 70 ro 70.1?
$ xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode shvga --rate 70.1

or

$ cvt 1024 768 70.1
# 1024x768 70.04 Hz (CVT) hsync: 56.18 kHz; pclk: 75.50 MHz
Modeline "1024x768_70.10"   75.50  1024 1080 1184 1344  768 771 775 802 -hsync +vsync 

$ xrandr --newmode shvga 75.50  1024 1080 1184 1344  768 771 775 802 -hsync +vsync
                         |
                         ^ 
                         This is not reliable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using a frequency that's actually supported by your monitor, as it is the frequency that is often "Out of Range". Finding a tech sheet for the monitor (usually on the OEM's site) should give you the required information.

Comment: i am doing that. Mostly the ranges that works are 60 to 70hz. And in my line of code, i have assigned that but it fails.